# Concatenating rows in the form "A1", "B2", "C3"

Tags: string, r, paste

I have a dataframe

```
> df
  letters numbers
1       A       1
2       B       2
3       C       3
4       D       4
5       E       5
```

and wanted to have the following result after concatenating the rows:

```
"A1","B2","C3","D4","E5"
```

in order to have the following:

```
c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5")
```

what's wrong with the following code?

```
> paste(df$letters, df$numbers, sep="",collapse='","')
[1] "A1\",\"B2\",\"C3\",\"D4\",\"E5"
```

Comment: Please, next time be more specific about what `wrong` means for your question. The fact that a lot of the answer did not answer your question correctly can be attributed to that.

Comment: Your code is not *wrong* -- you're just missing the opening and closing quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `data.frame`, you might want to try:

```
> do.call(paste0, df)
[1] "A1" "B2" "C3" "D4" "E5"
```

Or, if you want a single string with commas, modify your approach as follows:

```
> paste0(df$letters, df$numbers, collapse = ", ")
[1] "A1, B2, C3, D4, E5"
```

Getting the quotes in there is deceptive:

```
> paste0('"', paste0(df$letters, df$numbers, collapse = '", "'), '"')
[1] "\"A1\", \"B2\", \"C3\", \"D4\", \"E5\""
```

It looks like there are backslashes, but there aren't:

```
> cat(paste0('"', paste0(df$letters, df$numbers, collapse = '", "'), '"'))
"A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5"
> nchar(paste0('"', paste0(df$letters, df$numbers, collapse = '", "'), '"'))
[1] 28
```

---

Or, maybe you're looking for `dQuote`, `sQuote` or `shQuote` (hard to say not knowing why you want to do what you're doing):

```
> noquote(paste(dQuote(paste0(df$letters, df$numbers)), collapse = ", "))
[1] “A1”, “B2”, “C3”, “D4”, “E5”
> noquote(paste(shQuote(paste0(df$letters, df$numbers)), collapse = ", "))
[1] 'A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5'
> noquote(paste(sQuote(paste0(df$letters, df$numbers)), collapse = ", "))
[1] ‘A1’, ‘B2’, ‘C3’, ‘D4’, ‘E5’
```

Comment: I also want commas in the result string

Comment: The result string should have the form "A1","B2","C3","D4","E5" with both commas and inverted commas

Answer (score 1):

The `\` are escape characters to identify `"` that R prints around any string when using `print` and the `"` in the string itself. To get rid of the `\` you could use `'` in stead of `"`. Also, to get `'` around the string, also the first and last, you could use `sprintf` combined with `paste`:

```
> paste(sprintf("'%s%s'", letters[1:10], 1:10), collapse = ",")
[1] "'a1','b2','c3','d4','e5','f6','g7','h8','i9','j10'"
```

Comment: I want also the comma in the result

Comment: The result string should have the form "A1","B2","C3","D4","E5" with both commas and inverted commas

Comment: I added some stuff to my answer to clarify your isse.

Answer (score 1):

R reads `\"` as a `"` in a string. When you run `cat(paste0(df$letters, df$numbers, sep="",collapse='","'),"\n")` you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hat:

```
theString <- paste0(sprintf("\"%s%i\"", df$letters, df$numbers), collapse = ",")

cat(theString)
# "A1","B2","C3","D4","E5"
```